# Translation in languages with different alphabets in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, html, angular7

First, i m using ngx-translate for translation in Angular 7. I build a custom service. Translation is working but document alphabet is not changed. For Ex: 'REGISTER' word has english chars. The word has Turkish characters when I pass through Turkish. It transforms to 'REGİSTER'.

My Service Constructor:

```
  constructor(
private translate: TranslateService,
private cookieService: CookieService,
private store: Store<IAppState>,
@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: any
```

) {

}

My Service Use Method:

```
use(code: string) {
    const language = this.getLanguage(code);
    this._document.documentElement.lang = language.locale;
    this.translate.use(code);
    return language;
}
```

Comment: I'm really unclear what exactly you're asking or expecting…

Comment: i have similiar problem. When I change language, I also change html lang attribute but turkish characters still exist.